# I am getting this error java.sql.SQLException: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: java, mysql

I have two tables 1.users table(columns: branch_id) and 2.branches table(columns: branch_id,branch_name).

In my form i have a branch field which is select field. In that select field i need to get the values from branches table with column branch name. I did that functionality.

Now what is my requirement is, in database i need to insert the brach_id in users table which is in branches table based on that branch_name,

Here is My query functionality

```
 String query = "insert into users(full_name,gender,mobile_number,"
            + "email,password,department,designation,emp_code,branch_id,created_on,created_by,last_logged_on) "
            + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,"
            + "(select id from branches where branch_name=?),?,?,?)";
    if(con!=null){
        try{
         ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
         ps.setString(1, bean.getName());
         if(bean.getGender().equals("Female")){
             ps.setInt(2,1);
         }else{
             ps.setInt(2,0);
         }
         ps.setString(3, bean.getMobile());
         ps.setString(4, bean.getUserid());
         ps.setString(5, bean.getPassword());
         ps.setString(6, bean.getDepartment());
         ps.setString(7, bean.getDesignation());
         ps.setString(8, bean.getEmpcode());
         ps.setInt(9, bean.getBranchId());
         ps.setTimestamp(10, new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
         ps.setInt(11, bean.getCreatedBy());
         ps.setTimestamp(12, new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
         insert_flag=ps.executeUpdate();
```

I think query working fine. something error i am getting at prepared statement i don't think so.

can any one please help me.

if i pass the brach_name like this

`select id from branches where branch_name='"+branch+"'`in select query i am getting this error `java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (12 > number of parameters, which is 11).

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

This query `select id from branches where branch_name=?` is returning more than one result for some value of `branch_name`. You've got duplicate branch names in the branches table.

Comment: if i pass the branch like this (select id from branches where branch_name='"+branch+"') that branch i passed in method i am getting this error java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (12 > number of parameters, which is 11).

Answer (score 0):

Actually here you are inserting in single row and try to insert multiple row in column branch_id, so getting error. Just change below insert statement with your's and try-

```
 String query = "insert into users(full_name,gender,mobile_number,"
            + "email,password,department,designation,emp_code,branch_id,created_on,created_by,last_logged_on) "
            + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,"
            + "(select id from branches where branch_name=? limit 1),?,?,?)";
```

Comment: I added your code,but it is inserting always first id of branches table i.e.1. I want to insert the branch_name corresponding id value.  please help me its not working.

Comment: yes as I told that earlier problem was that you are trying to insert single row but multiple row value in single column....if you want bulk insert then either insert each row separately or first prepare your data in a temp table then use insert data from other table....or you can prepare a csv file and then bulk upload.